# Insert content of table variable into table

Tags: oracle, oracle11gr2

I have the following table, two types based on it, and a function that reads from this table:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
    ID RAW(16) NULL,
    NAME NVARCHAR2(200) NULL,
    ENTITYID RAW(16) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TYPE myRowType AS OBJECT (
    NAME NVARCHAR2(200),
    ENTITYID RAW(16)
);
CREATE TYPE myTableType IS TABLE OF myRowType;

CREATE FUNCTION myFunction(...) RETURN myTableType ...
```

As you can see, the type `myRowType` is similar to `myTable`, but not exactly.

**My goal is to insert rows into `myTable` based on the results of `myFunction`.**

The naive approach would be to just write:

```
INSERT INTO myTable(ID, NAME, ENTITYID)
    SELECT sys_guid(), NAME, ENTITYID
    FROM TABLE(myFunction(...));
```

But since `myFunction` reads from `myTable`, this leads to the following error:

```
ORA-04091: table myTable is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
```

So I have to split the `myFunction` call from the insert statement. I tried it like this:

```
DECLARE
    tbl myTableType;
BEGIN
    SELECT myRowType(x.NAME, x.ENTITYID)
        BULK COLLECT INTO tbl
        FROM TABLE(myFunction(...)) x;

    INSERT INTO myTable
        (ID, NAME, ENTITYID)
        SELECT sys_guid(), x.NAME, x.ENTITYID
        FROM tbl x;
END;
```

But here, Oracle doesn't seem to understand the `FROM tbl` clause. It shows the error

```
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

**How can I insert the rows in `tbl` into `myTable`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can't use a locally defined nested table as an argument for `TABLE` function, maybe you would consider using the `FORALL` bulk insert? I see you are using Oracle 11g, so you will be able to access fields of `myRowType`. You would then replace your `INSERT` from your PL/SQL block with this:

```
FORALL v_i IN tbl.FIRST..tbl.LAST
  INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (sys_guid(), tbl(v_i).name, tbl(v_i).entityid);
```

I recommend this great article by Tim Hall: [BULK COLLECT & FORALL](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/9i/bulk-binds-and-record-processing-9i.php)